# Compass don't compile @charset rule

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have `@charset "utf-8"` rule in my _base.scss partial and when I importing _base.scss in my master file @charset rule don't compile.
I try `@viewport {width:device-width;}` and it compile fine but @charset don't. Any idea where is the problem?

Yes it is the first rule in my _base.scss partial,I try other CSS @rules and they works fine but @charset don't want to compile in .css file.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I spent some time to figure this out. This is what I would consider to be a bug, though it might be considered an actual "feature" within SASS.

So even if you specify utf-8 encoding in your SASS file using:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

...if you don't use any non-ascii characters then it'll actually strip the charset definition out. There is presently (as far as I can find) no fix for this within any of the SASS distributions - and I looked HARD.

So, to force the charset definition to be rendered to the output .css file, I added the following dummy class that includes a non-ascii character and that made it start spitting out the charset right away:

```
//In your main .scss file - first line, first character:
@charset "UTF-8";
[more code...]
```

Then, in any file that's part of the SASS compilation, add the following rule:

```
.force-UTF-8{
    content: "¡";
}
```

You can name the rule anything you want, and you can change that inverted exclamation mark to anything else you want as long as it's a non-ascii character. You can type that character (at least on windows) by holding down "alt" and hitting "0-1-6-1" on the numpad. Just google non-ascii characters and you should be able to figure it out.

I know this is less than ideal but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the underlying SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#encodings) for `@charset` it looks like it has to be in the first line of the stylesheet:

> Add @charset "encoding-name"; at the beginning of the stylesheet
>   (before any whitespace or comments) and Sass will interpret it as the
>   given encoding. Note that whatever encoding you use, it must be
>   convertible to Unicode.

Comment: This is not helpful, since I already went that route. I'm having the same issue as the OP and my SASS still will not output the charset rule, even when using the charset directive as the first line/character or the stylesheet. Any other ideas? I have another project with an identical setup that DOES output @charset "UTF-8"; into the css, so it's weird that this wouldn't work...!